# strange behaviour of cout?

Tags: pointers, structure, cout

In a long assignment I found a miraculous behaviour of cout!!
`

```
for(i=0; i<ndel; i++)
    {
        cin>>a;
        head=Delete(head, a);
        cout<<"Deleting ";
        cout<<a<<endl;
            //cout<<"Deleting "<<a<<endl; /*this gives seg error*/

        printInts(head);
    }

`
```

The code works fine with

```
 cout<<a<<endl;
```

but gives a segmentation fault with

```
cout<<"Deleting "<<a<<endl;
```

Here's my Delete function:

```
node* Delete(node *T, int a)
{
    if(a==1 && T!=NULL)
    {
        T->flag=0;
        return T;
    }
    int arr[50];
    int n, i, tr_num; /* tr_num is the index of array corresponding to last node not to be deleted if the no. to be del is leaf*/
    node *tr, *ptr;  /*tr istracker on last pointer that cannot be deleted if it encounters leaf*/
    node *pth[50];
    n=find_binary(arr, a);
    tr=T;
    ptr=T;
    pth[0]=T;
    tr_num=0;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[n-2-i]==0)
        {
            if(ptr->left==NULL)
            {
                return T;
            }
            ptr=ptr->left;
            pth[i+1]=ptr;

            if((ptr->flag==1 && (ptr->right!=NULL || ptr->left!=NULL)) || (ptr->right!=NULL && ptr->left!=NULL))
            {
                tr_num=i+1;
                tr=ptr;
            }
        }

        if(arr[n-2-i]==1)
        {
            if(ptr->right==NULL)
            {
                return T;
            }
            ptr=ptr->right;
            pth[i+1]=ptr;

            if((ptr->flag==1 && (ptr->right!=NULL || ptr->left!=NULL)) || (ptr->right!=NULL && ptr->left!=NULL))
            {
                tr_num=i+1;
                tr=ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    ptr->flag=0;
    if(ptr->left==NULL && ptr->right==NULL)
    {
        for(i=n-1; i>=tr_num+1; i--)
        {
            delete pth[i];
            pth[i]=NULL;
        }
        if(arr[n-tr_num-2]==1)
        {
            pth[tr_num]->right=NULL;
        }
        else if(arr[n-tr_num-2]==0)
        {
            pth[tr_num]->left=NULL;
        }


    }


    return T;
}
```

Here's the find binary code..

```
int find_binary(int arr[], int num)
{
    int i=0;

    while(num!=0)
    {
        arr[i]=num%2;
        num=num/2;
        i++;
    }
return i;
}
```

In another instance:
I have a function with prototype

```
node * search(node *T, int a);
```

calling this function in main

```
    cout<<search(BT, 7);
```

works!
But

```
node *ptr=search(BT, 7);
```

gives segmentation error!! I am clueless why, because the similar assignment works completely fine in my delete function but in main it gives segmentation error!!
Note: node is a structure.
I compile using g++

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: If you're getting a segfault with innocuous code like this, it almost certainly means that you have a memory error somewhere else. Can you show us the code for Delete?